# Print button on newsletter

Tags: asp.net, html, printing, campaign-monitor

I need to implement a print option for the news letter i send through campaigmonitor.If its possible can any one suggest the idea behind this?

Comment: I think all email clients provide a _Print_ functionality. Why do you want to re-invent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can paste html code  in your document which will provide an option for printing

```
<input type="button"  onClick="window.print()" value="Print This Page"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can add arbitrary HTML/JavaScript, you are looking for `<a href="javascript:window.print()">print this</a>` or similar. Otherwise, you can advise the user to press CTRL+P, which should work on most systems.